# Cobol Printscreen to file

Tags: cobol, mainframe, printscreen

Rather simple question, that is very complicated in Cobol.

I need to print the screen to a file, just take whatever is on the screen and save it. Fileformat of the save is irrelevant, as long as I get the information out of Cobol.

Any help with this would be very much appriciated.

Comment: In pure Cobol, I would guess that's impossible. But you can link your cobol program to library written in another language that does the job wanted.

Comment: Which screen?  Your question is tagged "mainframe," are you in ISPF, CICS, IMS, etc. ?

Comment: L and CSC: The data I am looking for is in Mainframe/Extra!X-treme/IMS.

Comment: Do you want the COBOL program to write the same information being displayed on the screen to a file, or do you want the terminal emulator to scrape the screen to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is not complicated at all in Cobol.

I believe that the Cobol 85 standard (which all modern Cobols should adhere to) has the `ACCEPT ..... FROM SCREEN` statement.

Assuming you have a `LINE SEQUENTIAL` output file called, say, `SCREEN-DUMP-FILE`, with a file record of `SCREEN-DUMP-REC` you could dump the screen to this file using the following piece of code:

```
OPEN OUTPUT SCREEN-DUMP-FILE.
PERFORM VARYING SCREEN-LINE FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL SCREEN-LINE > 24
    ACCEPT SCREEN-DUMP-REC FROM SCREEN
           LINE SCREEN-LINE COL 1 SIZE 80
    WRITE SCREEN-DUMP-REC
END-PERFORM.
CLOSE SCREEN-DUMP-FILE.
```

Now that wasn't hard, was it?

Note that this code assumes a 'mainframe' terminal sizing which may be different in your case. Besides, most modern Cobols have a way of interrogating the actual screen size, so you could change the number of screen lines and the size of line to accept accordingly.

Comment: +1... This is an interesting idea, but not many "mainframe" applications use the COBOL-85 SCREEN capabilities. On mainframe systems CICS is more likely used where none of this would apply. But this was a really good try.

Answer (score 0):

[EXTRA! X-treme](http://www.attachmate.com/Products/Terminal+Emulation/Extra/xtreme/extra-x-treme.htm) is a terminal emulator from Attachmate for Windows machines.  You may want to check the documentation for that product.  Judging from this [demonstration video](http://www.attachmate.com/flash/extra%20x-treme%20demo/default.html), what you need to do may be as simple as selecting all the text in the emulator window, then choosing the Microsoft Office tool and pasting the text into a Word document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aviva mainframe emulator, insert this line just before action that takes you to next screen.

```
rc% = AppWin.SaveScreen("full file location with name of file and extension",2)
```

I am using this method to save screen to a .txt file. Option 2 appends output one after another. 
Hope it helps.